# ODR and internal linkage

Tags: c++, c++11, linkage, one-definition-rule

Assume that I have two compilation units in a single program, each of which declares a non-inline function with identical signatures, but differing in implementation, such as

```
// a.cpp
namespace internal {
    int foo(int a) {
        return a+1;
    }
}

int main() {
}
```

and

```
// b.cpp
namespace internal {
    int foo(int b) {
        return b+2;
    }
}
```

Compiling/linking this (g++ 4.8.3 with `-std=c++11`), I get an error

```
b.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `internal::foo(int)'
```

which is rather expected, since, as far as I understand, this is simply a violation of the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition):

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable
>   that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire
>   program (including any standard and user-defined libraries).

Now, changing the `namespace internal` into an unnamed namespace, the error goes away. Intuitively, this make sense to me, since I'm changing the function from [external to internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have external
>   linkage unless the namespace is unnamed or is contained within an
>   unnamed namespace (since C++11): variables and functions not listed
>   above (that is, functions not declared static [...]) ...

and

> [A]ll names declared in unnamed namespace or a namespace
>   within an unnamed namespace, even ones explicitly declared extern,
>   have internal linkage.

However, I was unable to find anything in the one definition rule that exempts functions with internal linkage from it. Therefore, my question is: Is my intuitive reasoning correct, or am I still violating the one definition rule with functions that have internal linkage (and the compiler/linker just doesn't report it anymore)? Additionally, where does the standard (or cppreference.com `:)`) say whether or not it is ok?

Comment: Your intuition is right. Finding the details from the standard will only reinforce it. If you are into language lawyering, that's a good goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

n4713

> §6.5 Program and linkage [basic.link]
>
> A name is said to have linkage when it might denote the same object,
>   reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name
>   introduced by a declaration in another scope:
>
> (2.1) — When a name has external linkage, the entity it denotes can be
>   referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from
>   other scopes of the same translation unit.
>
> (2.2) — When a name has internal linkage, **the entity it denotes can
>   be referred to by names from other scopes in the same translation
>   unit.**
>
> — When a name has no linkage, the entity it denotes cannot be referred
>   to by names from other scopes.

This basically says that (in the case of unnamed namespaces) the name `foo` from `a.cpp` and  the name `foo` from `b.cpp` each refer to different entities. So you don't have two definitions of the same object, so ODR is not violated.